# How to extract multiline content from the <pre> tag in html using Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, testing, pre

Originally the element looks like this:

```html
<pre>test_line1 test_line2 test_line3 test4</pre>
```

but when i double click it it looks like this:

```html
<pre>test_line1
test_line2
test_line3
test4</pre>
```

linebreaks here are not recognized as \n or 
what to do? i need to extract text and compare it with expected text
and expected text can be written only in single line

```js
String elementText = element.getText();
Assert.assertTrue(elementText,"test_line1 test_line2 test_line3 test4");
 Assert.assertTrue(elementText,"test_line1\ntest_line2\ntest_line3\ntest4");
```

Comment: What is the problem? Text content extracted from the `pre` element will contain all these texts

Comment: If something additional appears as symbol which is ignorable you can replace it with blank char in the actual text and later compare with the expected.

Comment: @Prophet the extracted text if i print it put will look like this:
test_line1
test_line2
test_line3
test4
how to understad what  element stands for new line if it is not \n

Comment: @AlexKaramfilov how to understand which symbol it is?

Comment: You can try with something like this address.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "");

Comment: Why is is important the new lines? You can remove the new line and leading and trailing space characters from the received text content and check if it contains the expected texts

Comment: You can mark the comment as helpful.

Comment: @AlexKaramfilov you can also post this as an answer with more explanations and topic starter will accept it

Comment: @AlexKaramfilov but there is not such button, probably because it is not in answers, but in comments

Comment: Add it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with something like this:

```
actualText.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "");
```

This will remove all potential new line symbols from the text.